# Get property of JSON

Tags: angularjs

I have the following on an angular controller:

```
$scope.emailsConfig = {
  valueField: 'email',
  labelField: 'name',
  options: [{email: 'brian@dn.cm', name: 'Brian'},
            {email: 'nikola@tl.com', name: 'Nikola'}],
}
```

Then I have the following:

```
<select selectize="emailsConfig" ng-model="emails"></select>
```

This works fine ... But then I changed options to:

```
options: UserService.GetEmails()
```

This does not work. When I logged options and get:

```
{"Emails":[{email: 'brian@dn.cm', name: 'Brian'}, {email: 'nikola@tl.com', name: 'Nikola'}]}
```

How can I get the values that are in Emails?

I tried UserService.GetEmails().Emails but somehow get undefined

**UPDATE**

UserService.GetEmails() is the following:

```
application.service('UserService', function ($http) {

  return {
    GetEmails: function () {
      return $http.get('api/users/emails');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly does `UserService.GetEmails()` do? does it perform an ajax request?

Comment: show us the service. Likely returning a promise or it may not be set up properly at all

Comment: Just added an update with information on the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service is returning the promise that `$http` returns. You still need to add the callback that returns the data. Can use `success()` or `then()`

Try this:

```
UserService.GetEmails().success(function(resp){    
    $scope.emailsConfig = {
      valueField: 'email',
      labelField: 'name',
      options: resp.Emails
    }

}).error(function(){
   alert('Ooops')
});
```

to move more of this into the service and out of the controller you could do something like:

```
application.service('UserService', function ($http) {
    return {
        GetEmails: function (callback) {
            $http.get('api/users/emails').success(function (resp) {
                var config = {
                    valueField: 'email',
                    labelField: 'name',
                    options: resp.Emails
                }
                callback(config);

            }).error(function () {
                alert('Oooops');
            });
        }
    }
}
```

then in controller

```
UserService.GetEmails(function(emailsConfig){
    $scope.emailsConfig = emailsConfig;
})
```

Comment: Somehow this breaks the select completely ... There is an example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/X2YYPX?p=preview. See the last two exemples in the HTML and in App.js

Comment: I solved it ... I needed to separate the config part from the data part. Thanks.